# How to merge ini file with overrides file

Tags: bash, merge, ini

Im looking for a way, ideally in bash to merge two ini files. Here are the details. I have one file which holds the "defaults" and another which JUST specifies the lines that should be changed.

so for example, we have the file `default.ini` that holds the default values:

```
[foo]
bar=1
baz=2
```

Then we have a seperate file `overrides.ini`, which holds the "overrides":

```
bar=10
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
[foo]
bar=10
baz=2
```

`patch` immediately sprang to mind, but I can't get that to work unless `overrides.ini` has ALL values in `default.ini` with `bar` changed (in which case I might as well just use `overrides.ini`)

`join` Seemed an option until I saw the requirement that the input files need to be sorted, which is not a possibility in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only `bar` in `default.ini`, you could use awk:

```
$ awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}($1 in a){$0=a[$1]}1' overrides default
```

Output:

```
[foo]
bar=10
baz=2
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F= '              # = is the delimiter
NR==FNR {                # process overrides file
    a[$1]=$0             # hash record, first field is the key
    next                 # process next override entry
}
($1 in a) {              # if ini entry is found in a hash
    $0=a[$1]             # replace with that
}1' overrides default    # output, mind the file order
```

Comment: This also works great with dotenv files! `awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}($1 in a){$0=a[$1]}1' .env.production .env`